# Mysql Convert into single select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-5.7

I have the following database ( with many more rows ):

[image]

There are dates and times for which I might have just `Temperature`, or `x-Axis Vibration`, or any field. Some timestamps (like the ones in this pic) have missing fields like `Z-Axis Vibration`

I want to fetch all this data in the following format and convert fields which are not found to 'NA'

[image]

I have tried the following query:

```
select entry_date, entry_time, field_name, ifnull(value, "NA") as value
from tablename 
where group_name = "SL1-DSM-1" and 
concat(entry_date, " ", entry_time) in 
    ( select distinct(concat(entry_date, " ", entry_time)) 
    from tablename 
    where timestamp(entry_date, entry_time) between "2019-07-22 00:00:00" and 
        "2019-07-23 00:00:00" ) and 
    field_name in (select distinct(field_name) from tablename where group_name = 
        "SL1-DSM-1");
```

This is giving me the result:

[image]

Is there a way this can be achieved using a single query ? Or in minimum no. of queries so as to make it faster.

*NOTE: Currently, I'm using different queries for each group and field, and compiling them into a common format, but I wanted if this could be returned my MySQL itself*

Comment: Do you only need an optimized query or you need to tweak your result also? If result also, please post your required result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've already posted my result that I want. Look at the 2nd pic attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all the rows using `cross join` and then fill in the missing values.  `'N/A'` is not a good fill in, because it is a string.  Just use `NULL`.

Something like this:

```
select entry_date, entry_time, group_name, field_name,
       t.value
from (select distinct entry_date, entry_time, group_name
      from tablename 
     ) dtg cross join
     (select distinct field_name
      from tablename
     ) f left join
     tablename t
     using (entry_date, entry_time, group_name, field_name)
```

Comment: It works exactly like I want it to :) can you please give a little description of what exactly is happening in your query ? thanks in advance

Comment: @mrid . . . I do in the first paragraph.  It generates all combinations of time/group and field that you want.  Then it populates the known values (the rest are `NULL`).

Comment: If this answer solved your problem. Mark it as the accepted answer. @mrid

Comment: @Pie LOL, I know how this forum works bro. I was just a little busy so couldn't test it out :)